# Places API for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

How can I get Places API for Android key, if I already have project in Google Maps Console. When I create Places API key, it says that I already have a key, but when I use this key, I receive `This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key`

Comment: Upon further investigation, double check if your key have *Key restriction*. Key restriction lets you specify which web sites, IP addresses, or apps can use this key. Check the [Best practices for securely using API keys](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en) to help you properly securing your API keys. *Note*: if you are using [Google Places Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key) use a server check. Use this [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places), to help you experiment on the API keys. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `applicationId` is same as what you used with registering your app when generating the API keys. Different package name or application id will render the eror you're seeing.